# multi column stacked bar plots

Tags: graphs, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a stacked bar plot, with groups of 3 columns. I figured out how to do that, but the columns go over each other no matter how I change the bar width or bar shift.

For a non-stacked graph everything works well.

The code and results are attached.

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
%\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[
every axis/.style={ 
    ybar stacked,
    ymin=0,ymax=1500,
    symbolic x coords={
      \#5,\#6,\#7, \#8, \#15, \#16, \#18, \#19, \#22},
    bar width=3.5pt,
      legend style={font=\small, at={(0,1)},anchor=north west, draw=none},
    ylabel={size},
     ymode=log,
        log basis y={10},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={font=\small, 
    },
    point meta=rawy,
  },
]


\begin{axis}[bar shift=-5pt] 
\addplot coordinates {(\#5,3) (\#6,27) (\#7,81) (\#8, 243) (\#15, 16) (\#16,256) (\#18, 4) (\#19, 18)(\#22,4)};
\addplot coordinates {(\#5,3) (\#6,5) (\#7,6) (\#8, 8) (\#15, 12) (\#16, 113) (\#18, 5) (\#19, 18) (\#22,1)}; 
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[bar shift=0pt,hide axis] 
\addplot+[] coordinates {(\#5,4) (\#6,28) (\#7,82) (\#8, 244) (\#15, 18) (\#16, 257) (\#18, 4) (\#19, 18) (\#22,8)}; 
\addplot+[pattern=north east lines] coordinates {(\#5,4) (\#6,6) (\#7,7) (\#8, 8) (\#15, 13) (\#16,113) (\#18, 5) (\#19, 18)(\#22,6)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[bar shift=4pt,hide axis] 
\addplot+[pattern=north east lines] coordinates {(\#5,9) (\#6,81) (\#7,243) (\#8, 729) (\#15, 864) (\#16,1280) (\#18, 4) (\#19, 18)(\#22,1000000)}; 
\addplot+[] coordinates {(\#5,6) (\#6,8) (\#7,9) (\#8, 10) (\#15, 44) (\#16, 155) (\#18, 5) (\#19, 18) (\#22,100000)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! I cannot reproduce this result if I wrap your code fragment into `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` (and remove `ymin=0`, which is not valid for a logarithmic plot). Please provide a complete document that yields the problematic output.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. I've edited the question, it should compile now.

Answer (score 1):

According to what I find increasing the `bar shift` does work. Please see the code annotations for the changes.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} % <- 1.15 also works

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[
/pgfplots/every axis/.style={ % <- added /pgfplots/ 
    ybar stacked,
    ymax=1500, %<- removed ymin
    symbolic x coords={
      \#5,\#6,\#7, \#8, \#15, \#16, \#18, \#19, \#22},
    bar width=3.5pt,
      legend style={font=\small, at={(0,1)},anchor=north west, draw=none},
    ylabel={size},
     ymode=log,
        log basis y={10},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={font=\small, 
    },
    point meta=rawy,
  },
]


\begin{axis}[bar shift=-6pt] %<- increased
\addplot coordinates {(\#5,3) (\#6,27) (\#7,81) (\#8, 243) (\#15, 16) (\#16,256) (\#18, 4) (\#19, 18)(\#22,4)};
\addplot coordinates {(\#5,3) (\#6,5) (\#7,6) (\#8, 8) (\#15, 12) (\#16, 113) (\#18, 5) (\#19, 18) (\#22,1)}; 
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[bar shift=0pt,hide axis] 
\addplot+[] coordinates {(\#5,4) (\#6,28) (\#7,82) (\#8, 244) (\#15, 18) (\#16, 257) (\#18, 4) (\#19, 18) (\#22,8)}; 
\addplot+[pattern=north east lines] coordinates {(\#5,4) (\#6,6) (\#7,7) (\#8, 8) (\#15, 13) (\#16,113) (\#18, 5) (\#19, 18)(\#22,6)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[bar shift=6pt,hide axis] %<- increased
\addplot+[pattern=north east lines] coordinates {(\#5,9) (\#6,81) (\#7,243) (\#8, 729) (\#15, 864) (\#16,1280) (\#18, 4) (\#19, 18)(\#22,1000000)}; 
\addplot+[] coordinates {(\#5,6) (\#6,8) (\#7,9) (\#8, 10) (\#15, 44) (\#16, 155) (\#18, 5) (\#19, 18) (\#22,100000)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks!!!

Comment: Do you happen to know how can I add a legend that contains all the information? (three columns and two "stacks" )

Comment: @user200012 Well, if you provide some precise information, I may give it a shot. "(three columns and two "stacks" )" has many possible interpretations. The cleaner way to proceed, though, would be to accept this answer and use it as the basis of a new question.